# First Day of Previous Month

Tags: apex

I am setting up a batch class to create records on the First of every month. These records will be datestamped with the 1st day of the prior month.  Is the following line correct syntax or do I need to break it into 2 lines?

```
Date PriorMonth = System.today().toStartOfMonth.addMonths(-1);
```

or

```
Date CurrentMonth = System.today().toStartOfMonth();
Date PriorMonth = CurrentMonth.addMonths (-1);
```

Comment: Setting aside the missing parenthesis for your `toStartOfMonth()` call, this would be something you could test quickly using anonymous apex, is it not?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that as I've never used it. I'll try there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done on a single line. The anonymous apex to verify this is simply `System.debug(System.today().toStartOfMonth().addMonths(-1));`

Looking at the documentation is another way to see if you can chain methods together.
The [Date class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_date.htm) tells us the following (I think it's safe to assume that `System.today()` gives us a `Date`).

- `toStartOfMonth()` returns a `Date`
- `addMonths()` is a method that the `Date` class provides

Expressions are generally evaluated from left to right, so in this case that would look like

1. `System.today().toStartOfMonth().addMonths(-1)`
2. `<date instance>.toStartOfMonth().addMonths(-1)`
3. `<date instance, start of current month>.addMonths(-1)`
4. `<date instance, start of previous month>`